# show div on pointer jquery

Tags: jquery, contextmenu

does anybody have jquery code that will show a div where the pointer is on click event?

I want to build a simple context menu but can only find a javascript example.

Answer (score 0):

you mean like?

```
$(function(){

    $('a.foo').click(function(){
       $('div.bar').show();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

a little [example](http://jsfiddle.net/8W6nU/) on jsfiddle.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#showText').click(function() {
        $('#toShow').show();
    });

    $('#hideText').click(function() {
        $('#toShow').hide();
    });
```

`});`